# Can Google Pay be used in webviews

Tags: webview, wkwebview

Can Google Pay be implemented in Webviews/WKWebview/SFSafariViewController for both IOS device and Android devices?

Google pay FAQ page said "For Android apps which use WebViews, you must invoke platform specific Android Google Pay APIs." - I'm not sure what does that mean...

Most other question I saw involves Stripe, I'm not using Stripe however.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enable Google Pay or Apple Pay directly, you must always have a payment operator for that, e.g. Stripe and many others.

However, even if you integrate Google and Apple pay via Stripe, it will work only in browser and native. It will not work via WebView unfortunately because the WebView container has less privileges than browser or native.

Comment: if i would configure it via stripe, is it going to be ok? i would not have a policy validation?